# How to White List both IP and Some of the Services for a traffic

Tags: istio

I am trying to white list different set of peers for example some set of IPs, some set of services (using label), some set of namespaces, etc.

Below are the things I have tried but it didn’t work as expected,

- A Rule with multiple handler-instance pair. Each pair is white listing individual set.
- Multiple rules with same matching condition and having different handlers to white list individual sets.

Result: In both the case there is ANDing between the outcome of each handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the issue adding authorized networks for cluster master access.

Authorized networks allow you to whitelist specific CIDR ranges and allow IP addresses in those ranges to access your cluster master endpoint using HTTPS. Authorized networks are compatible with all clusters [1].

If what you want it is not impleneted yet on Google Cloud, you can open a new feature request on this URL [2].

---

[1] https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/authorized-networks

[2] https://issuetracker.google.com

Comment: Alan, thanks for the reply. I guess authorized-network is used to whitelist IPs to access control-plane components.
My question is about any application service that is deployed in Istio controlled mesh (plz let me know if I need to edit or add more details to the question). Istio provides whitelist feature with the help of Rule-Instance-Handler. Multiple handler if used to whitelist an IP set and Services (by label), it actually doesn't allow the whitelisted traffic. This may be because each handler is whitelisting only one set.